# Liquibase plugin for gradle

Tags: java, gradle, liquibase

I've been looking for a liquibase gradle plugin and found [gradle-liquibase-plugin](https://github.com/tlberglund/gradle-liquibase-plugin) from **tlberglund**.

Gradle version 1.2

build file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'liquibase'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.2.8')
    compile('org.hsqldb:sqltool:2.2.8')
    compile('com.h2database:h2:1.3.167')
    compile('org.liquibase:liquibase-core:2.0.1')
    compile('com.augusttechgroup:groovy-liquibase-dsl:0.7.3')
    compile('postgresql:postgresql:9.1-901.jdbc4')
}

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.augusttechgroup:gradle-liquibase-plugin:0.6.1'
    }
}

databases {
    postgre {
        url = "${postgreBaseUrl}" + "${postgreDB}"
        username = "${postgreUserName}"
        password = "${postgreUserPassword}"
    }
}

changelogs {
    main {
        file = file('src/main/liquibase/mainChanges.groovy')
    }
}

task dbInit << {
    databases.postgre.url = "${postgreBaseUrl}"
    databases.postgre.username = "${postgreRootUserName}"
    databases.postgre.password = "${postgreRootUserPassword}"
    changelogs.main.file = file('src/main/liquibase/tablespaceChanges.groovy')
}
```

Runnin `gradle build` fails with the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find group:com.augusttechgroup, module:gradle-liquibase-plugin, vers
ion:0.6.1.
  Required by:
      :demo:unspecified

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to
get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Does anyone have experience with this plugin, I would really appreciate a working example.

Comment: Did you manage to get this plugin working ? While I'm able to get it to work, I find it a lot buggy and would like to have feedback and see if I'm the only one experiencing strange issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't related to the Liquibase plugin. You just need to declare a repository in the `buildscript {}` section. `buildscript {}` is completely separate from the rest of the script. You can almost think about it as a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source on github (see the build.gradle file) it looks like the builds are posted on oss.sonatype.org.  Try using adding "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" as a maven repository

So, your build.gradle may look like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url uri('https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/')
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group:'net.saliman', name: 'gradle-liquibase-plugin', version: '1.0.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'liquibase'
```